# Show that $F(x)=o(x^{1/q} )$, where $x \to +\infty$, whith $q=\frac{p-1}{p}.$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in \mathcal{L}^p$, with $1<p<+\infty$. For all $x\geqslant 0$, we define  $\displaystyle{F(x)= \int_0^x f(t)dt}$.

1. Show that $F$ is uniformely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Show that $F(x)=o(x^{1/q} )$, where $x \to +\infty$, whith $q=\frac{p}{1-p}.$

My attempt :

1. let $0\leqslant x \leqslant y,$
   \begin{align*}|F(y)-F(x)|&=\left|\int_x^yf(t)dt\right|\\&\leqslant\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{[x,y]}(t)|f(t)|dt\\&  \leqslant (y-x)^{1/q} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(t)|^p dt \right)^{1/p} \text{(by Hölder's inequality)} \\&\leqslant(y-x)^{1/q}\; ||f||p.\end{align*}
2. Let $a>0$ (fixed) and $x>a$, $|F(x)-F(a)|\leqslant (x-a)^{1/q}\; ||f||p$, then

$|F(x)|\leqslant  |F(a)|+(x-a)^{1/q}\; ||f||p$ $\implies $ $\dfrac{|F(x)|}{x^{1/q}}\leqslant  \dfrac{|F(a)|}{x^{1/q}}+(1-\frac{a}{x})^{1/q}\; ||f||p$.

I got stuck here, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In point 2, what does your work so far tell you about $$\limsup_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\lvert F(x)\rvert}{x^q}\,?$$

Comment: Thanks you @Daniel,  firstly my english is not very well !  2.$F(x)= O(x^{1/q}\;)$, but i'm looking to prove $ F(x)= o(x^{1/q}\;) $ !

Comment: Yes, what you have gives you $O(x^{1/q})$, but it gives you a bit more. You can get a bound for the $\limsup$ from it. What is the bound?

Comment: $$\limsup_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\lvert F(x)\rvert}{x^{1/q}}\,= ||f||_p ?$$

Comment: It must be $\leqslant$. You don't have equality in Hölder's inequality (generally), and the triangle inequality usually also gives a strict inequality, thus you shouldn't expect equality here. But the inequality is what we want. We're really close now. If you look at your derivation, do you really need the full $\lVert f\rVert_p$? Can you replace it with something smaller perhaps?

Comment: what do you think about : 
\begin{align*} |F(x)-F(a)| &\leqslant \int_a^x |f(t)|dt \\&\leqslant(x-a)^{1/q}\left(\int_a^x|f(t)|^pdt \right)^{1/p} ,\end{align*} then 
$$\dfrac{|F(x)|}{x^{1/q}} \leqslant \dfrac{|F(a)|}{x^{1/q}}+\left(1-\dfrac{a}{x}\right)^{1/q}\left(\int_a^x|f(t)|^pdt \right)^{1/p}, $$
so we need that $$\left(\int_a^x|f(t)|^pdt \right)^{1/p} \xrightarrow{x \to +\infty}0 $$
is that true ?

Comment: Excellent. It's not true (in general) that $$\biggl( \int_a^x \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt\biggr)^{1/p} \xrightarrow{x \to +\infty} 0,$$ it tends to $\lVert f\cdot \chi_{[a,+\infty)}\rVert_p$ (where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function of the set $S$). But that gives us $$\limsup_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\lvert F(x)\rvert}{x^{1/q}} \leqslant \lVert f\cdot \chi_{[a,+\infty)}\rVert_p\,.$$ And now, a small step takes us to the finish line.

Comment: i can put the answer in  a comment.

Comment: @DanielFischer please can you check the solution?!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that $\displaystyle{ \left(\int_a^x|f(t)|^pdt \right)^{1/p} \xrightarrow{\color{red}{a} \to +\infty}0}$ $\implies$  $\displaystyle{ \left(\int_a^x|f(t)|^pdt \right)^{1/p} \xrightarrow{x \to +\infty}0}$, so

for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $ a_{\varepsilon}$ : $\forall x\geqslant a_{\varepsilon}$,  $\displaystyle{ \left(\int_a^x|f(t)|^pdt \right)^{1/p}} \leqslant \varepsilon/2.$

$ \dfrac{|F(a)|}{x^{1/q}} \xrightarrow{x \to +\infty}{}0 $ $\implies$ $\exists$ $x_{\varepsilon} >0$ :  $\forall x> x_{\varepsilon}$, $\dfrac{|F(a)|}{x^{1/q}} \leqslant \varepsilon/2.$

For $\displaystyle {m=max(x_{\varepsilon} ,a_{\varepsilon})}$, we have $\dfrac{|F(x)|}{x^{1/q}} \leqslant \varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon, $  for all $x\geqslant m$.

what do you think?

Comment: The first line isn't right. I think you have mostly the right idea, but cannot yet get it precise and write it out correctly. That will come. In what comes after, all occurrences of $a$ ought to be $a_{\varepsilon}$, apart from that, the remainder after the first line is correct. In the first line, for the first term we get problems when $a > x$. I guess you intended to always have $x>a$, but that needs to be stated. And then, is it totally obvious what "$a\to+\infty$" means in that situation? The second part of that line is more serious: For every fixed $a$, $\int_a^x\lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt$

Comment: is nondecreasing, and non-negative for $x \geqslant a$. Thus the limit for $x \to +\infty$ is only $0$ if $f$ vanishes (a.e.) for $t\geqslant a$. To get $0$ as the limit we need to have $a \to +\infty$ in our statement. The easiest way around those difficulties is to remove the $x$ altogether in the first line. We have $$\biggl(\int_a^{+\infty} \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt\biggr)^{1/p} = \lVert f\cdot \chi_{[a,+\infty)}\rVert_p \xrightarrow{a \to +\infty} 0$$ by (pick your favourite of) dominated convergence, monotone convergence, or the reverse Fatou lemma.

Comment: Now, since $\biggl(\int_a^x \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt\biggr)^{1/p} \leqslant \lVert f\cdot \chi_{[a,+\infty)}\rVert_p$ you can go on as you did. We can make it shorter however. We have $$\limsup_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\lvert F(x)\rvert}{x^{1/q}} \leqslant \lVert f\cdot \chi_{[a,+\infty)}\rVert_p$$ for every $a$. But the left hand side doesn't depend on $a$ at all, hence the inequality holds if we replace the right hand side with the infimum over all $a$. But that is $0$, hence we're done.

Comment: thank you @DanielFischer ! i really appreciate your help !                                      One more question please :  If we want to use the dominated convergence theorem and we choose a sequence $f\cdot \chi_{[a_n \,,+\infty)}$  how to show that it converges to 0 from a mathematical redaction point of view? you can take it as a trivial question but i need to see the redaction if you can.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "redaction". The proof using the dominated convergence theorem goes: we have $\lvert f(t)\chi_{[a,+\infty)}(t)\rvert^p \leqslant \lvert f(t)\rvert^p$ for all $t$ and all $a$, and $\lvert f(t)\rvert^p \in L^1$. For a sequence $a_n \to +\infty$ we have $\lvert f(t)\chi_{[a_n,+\infty)}(t)\rvert^p \to 0$ for all $t$ (it's certainly $0$ as soon as $a_n > t$), hence by DCT $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{a_n}^{+\infty} \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt = 0\,.$$

Comment: I did not understand only why the sequence converges to 0 because I did not pay attention to the fact that $a_n> t$, now i got it. thank you so much !